# deploying a django app on osx

Tags: django, macos, server, wsgi

I am using **OS X El Capitan** with server app v 5.1.

I created a simple app using Django in `/Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps`. The app is called mysite (actually it is an empty app created with django).

Can anyone help me with the deployment of this app? I cannot seem to find any documentation or tutorial on how to do this.  Is there a way to add it to the server app and which `.conf` or `.wsgi` or com.something should I change.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have to use Server.app from Apple. Unless they have updated it, which is highly unlikely, it ships an ancient mod_wsgi version.

Comment: Yes I am running Server.app as I am really noob when it comes to terminal use, I feel everything is out of control. There should be an easy way to edit a configuration and a plist file, but at this stage I am open to any there alternative but just on osx.

Comment: For a start ``pip install mod_wsgi`` and use ``mod_wsgi-express`` from the command line to work on your application. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and for the link, I will check it and come back here in case I have another question :)

Comment: For using ``mod_wsgi-express`` also see http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/introducing-modwsgi-express.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/using-modwsgi-express-with-django.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/integrating-modwsgi-express-as-django.html

Comment: I actually made it half to work, now i am getting an " ImportError: No module named mysite.settings "; basically I created a plist file with the installation indicator path pointing to the wigs file, and adjusting the include to include a httpd_ file that I also created and added to the apache2 folder. so I guess I am on the right way? PS:this was done without installing anything, just using the server.app

Comment: Make sure you add ``--working-directory`` option with argument being the parent directory of your Django project. This can be necessary if running it from a different directory, or you have changed the meaning of ``BASE_DIR`` in the Django settings file if using Django management command integration,

Comment: Can you point me to a simple tutorial on where and how to add this option? I really do apologize for the annoyance and thank you for your patience. I am just working inside the project created by django.

Comment: You are going to have to explain more about how you are running ``mod_wsgi-express`` now. Are you using ``start-server``? Are you using ``setup-server`` and then using generated ``apachectl``? What options are you providing if either of these cases? You can see all the options you can supply by running the command with the ``--help`` option.

Comment: Actually I am working just with the graphical interface and trying to work with the .wsgi file. I really don't want to waste your time, it might be an error in the deployment of the site. I'll go get a good night sleep and check back in the morning. Or simply go back to building the site in php :p.